# The Challenge Square

Tags: geometry, dissection

[image]

Q: Can you divide this shape into 4 equal parts, and then form a square?

Comment: Well the problem is that you must make a square whit the 4 equal parts, there can be no leftovers, and nothing may overlap.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it like this:

> [image: solution]

The cut starts right in the center of those sides.