# Cutting a 10-by-2 rectangle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

How does one dissect a $10\times2$ rectangle into four pieces that can be reassembled to form a square?

Comment: can the rectangle only be cut into unit sizes? does the square need to be completely filled in? an area of 20 square units can't be evenly divided into a square with whole-number sides. need more info

Comment: @dperry: This is a standard dissection problem, without any strange requirements. This site contains many other puzzles of this type, as for instance http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/the-challenge-square

Comment: @dperry: I'm assuming the square needs to be completely filled in, otherwise you could just do four 2 x 2.5 blocks and make a 4.5 x 4.5 square with a hole in the middle.

Comment: Please could someone give me the <hidden> formatl I would like to give an answer.

Comment: @Hugh >!yourText

Comment: Are you allowed to flip the pieces over?

Comment: Area of rectangle $=20$, implies side of square $2\sqrt 5$. Am I right?

Comment: @Hugh: take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup  for a nice little guide

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Index your rectangle from (0,0) to (10,2). Then cut from

> (3,0) to (4,2); (4,2) to (8,0); (8,0) to (9,2).

These four pieces can be used to make the square.

> [image: Dissection]

Note that this dissection works without any flipping or even any rotation of the pieces!  To show that it's a square is also relatively simple.  Easy geometry shows that the angles are right angles, and that the sides are $2\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Any reason why you do not shift all the cut to the left by one unit so that the outer parts are symmetric? =)

Comment: That's a good observation, which probably reveals something about my brain. Or at least the way I came to the solution!

Comment: If you make the long cut first and slide the pieces appropriately, you can make this in two cuts instead of three! :D

Comment: That's true.  Also, the initial long cut can be anywhere between a vertical line at 1 and a vertical line at 9.  All it does is shift where the line in the central parallelogram of the square goes.

Comment: @corsiKa: But it's still four pieces, and the piece count is what the puzzle specifies.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I can do it with 4 cuts, 5 pieces

> Cut two 4x2 sections (2 cuts). Cut them diagonally (4 total cuts). The diagonals have length $\sqrt{20}$.  Assemble them so the diagonals are the sides of the new square, length 4 against length 2. That leaves a 2x2 hole in the middle, for your remaining 2x2 piece.

Comment: So inspired by this answer I tried it myself

Answer (score 7):

Big square: Actually 2 - Inside (10x10) and outside (10.5x10.5).

> 2 cuts (or 3 without stacking)  Cut piece in half parallel with the long side, giving 2  10x1 pieces.  Stack these pieces together, and cut in the same manner, giving 4  10x0.5 pieces.  Arrange these pieces so that the short ends are against then end of the next piece, forming a large square

Picture:

> [[image: 10x10]

Comment: I like this answer!  I guess it's a square perimeter, but you can't argue that this doesn't answer this question.

Comment: You can make it two cuts without stacking by simply cutting along the horizontal middle then the vertical middle to make four 5x1s.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a four-piece solution, taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96776/dissection-of-a-1-times-5-rectangle-to-a-square) (the link only has pictures, but I supplemented with cut locations):

> Cut from (0, 2) to (4, 0), from (4, 0) to (4 + $\sqrt{3}$, 2), and from (10 - $\sqrt{3}$, 0) to (10, 2).

Image of the cut-up rectangle:

> [image]

Then just slide the four pieces into a (rotated) square:

> [image]
>  
>  Despite the irrational locations of the cuts in the original rectangle, the vertices of all pieces in the joined square are at integer locations.